# How to pack a jar inside a dll and on runtime write the jar path to the memory?

Tags: java, memory, dll

So what my objective is, is to pack a JAR file inside a dll and on runtime write the jar path to the memory, (so that it wouldn't be phyiscally accessible on my hard drive) and then pack the dll itself.

This is my solution to making my product harder to reverse engineer. I've been reading a few pages about using native etc etc - but I cannot find a lot on this specific "packing" topic.

What I would like to do:
Pack jar inside a DLL
Write memory to jar path on runtime
Pack the DLL inside an exe.

Comment: You won't slow done reverse-engineering at all with this approach since the resources within a DLL and exe are just as easy to inspect as they are within a jar-file. You only give yourself a headache, waste resources on unpacking stuff, ... . There are definitely better ways of DRM.

Comment: @Paul can you suggest any other way that would be effective? Baring in mind - I'm amongst a community of children (minecraft) and so it's fairly safe anyway from the current population of developers.

Comment: I'd just use an obfuscator. Doubtful anyone on this level will go through reverse-engineering byte-code.

Comment: @Paul I understand - it is obfuscated. Though I wanted to go further. Thank you for your help.